# What does this max code do?

Tags: javascript

This is a very simple example that I'm hoping some of you guys can answer. This is a function that's supposed to return the largest value given in the parameters. But the thing is that I don't understand *how* it does it.

```
function max(a, b) {
  return [a, b][ +(a < b) ];
}
```

I'm used to the max function looking like this so I don't know how the above works:

```
function max(a, b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

If someone can explain to me how exactly this code finds the largest number, that be very helpful. For example, why is he using an array? And why is the unary `+` being used in such a way? (I'm new to JS).

Comment: Gotta love code golf `:P` Who wrote that?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That's some bad golfing: it's longer than the reasonable implementation! I hope this isn't in real code...

Comment: @JeremyBanks I used the wrong smiley. My reaction was [this](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/are-you-serious-face-seriously).

Comment: I think stuff like this is kind of fun and interesting to read, but ya, I definitely wouldn't use it in any situation where someone else would have read it.

Comment: Another reason not to use it besides readability is performance: http://jsperf.com/fancy-max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(a < b)` - evaluates to a boolean `true`/`false`

`+(a < b)`  typecasts the boolean to an int, so you'll have `0` or `1`

`[+(a < b)]`  - becomes an array index, `[0]` or `[1]`

`[a,b][+(a<b)]` - with the `[0]` or `[1]`, will yank the `a` or `b` value from a new temporary array `[a,b]`.

Comment: By array "dereference" you mean array "index"?

Comment: yeah. sorry. overthinking it a bit.

Comment: @typedeftypename `0`, and `1` are array indexes. `[0]`, and `[1]` are applications of the property accessor expression.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc B. You broke it down in to simple steps any beginner can understand: `a < b` is a boolean, arrays are 0-indexed, and `+` coerces into a number corresponding to the resulting boolean.

Comment: @typedeftypename: almost. + coerces booleans into numbers.

Comment: @MarcB *Only* booleans? Are you sure? So if I use `+` on any other object it won't return a number? Then what *will* it do?

Comment: @typedef: `alert(typeof(+(new String)))` does output "number". can't say it'll hold for ALL objects, but let's say that most of the standard "base type" ones do.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is less than `b`, the result is `true`, which converts to the number `1` because of the unary `+` operator.

Otherwise the result is `false` and it converts to `0`.

So the `0` and `1` are used as indices to get the values from the Array.

---

Think of it like this:

```
function max(a, b) {
    var arrayOfValues = [a, b],
        a_is_less_than_b = a < b,
        index;

    if (a_is_less_than_b)
       index = 1;
    else
       index = 0;

    return arrayOfValues[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario:**

1. `[a, b]` creates an array holding both elements with indices 0 and 1;
2. `(a < b)` returns a boolean value `true` or `false`;
3. `+(false|true)` is casting boolean to numeric type, so it becomes 0 or 1;
4. `[a, b][0|1]` returns element from the array under corresponding index.

**Example:**

```
 var a = 1, b = 2;
```

1. `[1, 2]`;
2. `(1 < 2) === true`;
3. `+(true) === 1`;
4. `[1, 2][1] === 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You create an array that consists of `a` and `b`, then you decide which index you want. I'll expand it:

```
function max(a, b) {
  var arr = [a,b];
  var aLTb = (a < b); // a boolean - whether or not a is less than b
  var index = +aLTb; // convert boolean to 0 or 1, which gives us an index
  return arr[index];
}
```